# How to find a file in server based on name in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, server.mappath

I have an xml named Mapping.xml stored in my local system.  i am accessing in code ,in my local system like `XDocument xd = new XDocument(@"D:\MVCPopup\Mapping.xml");` .But i don't think this will work if i deploy it in iis server due to the folder structure change.Do we have a generic mechanism which will find the file Mapping.xml. Will Server.Mappath will work here?

Answer (score 1):

`Server.MapPath` returns the phisical address from a virtual one. So if you configure a virtual folder on the iis that maps to the folder you save your XML in, then yes, `Server.MapPath` will help.